# This ongoing tragedy cannot be blamed (on/for) any lack of aggressiveness on the part of law enforcement

Tags: prepositions

> This ongoing tragedy cannot be blamed (on/for) any lack of aggressiveness on the part of law enforcement [link](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/03/opinion/violence-criminal-justice.html)​

I want to know what's the correct word for the bracket.
I think that either of them is correct to use there but "for" seems to be way more natural as I've lots of times come across only "blame someone or something" for something"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On** is the correct word here. You can blame somebody or something **for** a bad thing, or you can blame a bad thing **on** somebody or something.